# Update a third table from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Which ID's should match up based on the 'orderID'.

for example, Table1.ID = 1 & orderid 3. Should match to Table2.ID = 2 with the orderid = 3.

the relationship with those 2 id's are stored in table3 as described below.

```
UPDATE table3
SET table1ID, table2ID =(
SELECT table1.1ID, table2.2ID
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.orderid = b.orderid
)
```

```
    Table1            Table2                 Table3
1ID, orderid       2ID, orderid        3ID, table1ID, table2ID
 1      3           1       1           1       1         2
 2      2           2       3           2       2         3
 3      1           3       2           3       3         1
```

I am trying to update the table1ID in Table 3 where the value is null, but am unsure of how to write the query So that it still matches up accordingly.

```
   Table1            Table2                 Table3
1ID, orderid       2ID, orderid        3ID, table1ID, table2ID
 1      3           1       1           1                 2
 2      2           2       3           2                 3
 3      1           3       2           3       3         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes untested, but I believe it should work.

[You need to quote columns starting with a number.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

The idea is to retrieve matching pairs from `table1` and `table2` and then update `table3` accordingly on condition that `table3.table1id IS NULL` so that no value gets overwritten.

```
UPDATE
  table3 t
  LEFT JOIN (
    select     x.`1ID`, y.`2ID`
    from       table1 x
    inner join table2 y on x.orderid = y.orderid
  ) foo ON t.table2id = foo.`2ID`
SET
  t.table1id = foo.`1ID`
WHERE
  t.table1id IS NULL
```

Attaching SQLFiddle. Click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1e90) to see how it works.

Comment: @user2168066 I've edited my answer. Please be sure to see it now.